# display Excel PivotTable Data Source as cellvalue

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to find a way to display PivotTable Data Source in excel worksheet. I know we can manually view the Data source by clicking on PivotTable Tools Analyze > Change Data Source > Change Data source to display source in a separate window. I would like to know if it is possible dynamically display the source value as text in a linked cell(sample cell F4 below).

It can be one way relationship, meaning changing PivotTable Data Source, the display cell should be automatically updated, but changing the cell value in display cell does not necessary lead to change in PivotTable Data source. (**but if it change be done for both directions, would be even better.)

welcome both VBA and non-VBA solutions.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

[image: pivottable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create this function.

```
Function PivotTableSource(myPivot As String) As String
    Dim rawSource As String
    Dim a1Source As String
    Dim bracket As Long

    Application.Volatile
    rawSource = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(myPivot).SourceData
    a1Source = Application.ConvertFormula(rawSource, xlR1C1, xlA1)
    bracket = InStr(1, a1Source, "]")
    PivotTableSource = "=" & Mid(a1Source, bracket + 1)
End Function
```

Then put `=PivotTableSource("PivotTable1")` in cell F4.  PivotTable1 is the default name of the first Pivot Table created in a spreadsheet.  Change it if your pivot table is named something else.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to look at the events associated to the PivotTable Data Source, in the Microsoft documentation for example.

If there is an event triggered on the Data Source change, you can create a handler to update the value in the F4 cell.

Recording a macro while changing the Data Source of the PivotTable might also give some interesting hints.